# How to set breakpoint inside with part of try-with expression?

Tags: f#

```
try
    raise (InvalidOperationException())
with e -> 
    printfn "WTF"
```

I want debugger to stop at line `printfn "WTF"`, but this does not happen. Neither in Visual Studio, nor in LinqPad.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just tried it in VS code and it breaks normally on the printfn statement.

Comment: @3615 Wow, need to try it as well.

Answer (score 2):

When debugger in IDE is not attaching as you wish, you can call debugger break in the code to be sure it will be catched.

```
with e ->
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
    printfn "WTF"
```